# Azure Preview Portal says "Nothing to display"

Tags: azure

I wonder if that's just me or what. I'm very new to this so decided to have a play with the portal and preview portal. In the full view portal I've created just a quick web-site, that I've now had for about 20 minutes. But when I go `Browse -> Websites`, it says "Nothing to display" instead of displaying my web-site. When I go and click the giant plus sign + `NEW`, and try to add a web-site through there with the same name I've created through the full portal - it says site already exists, and I cannot select or do anything for it to pick up the web-site I've created through the full view.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on both pages to no avail.

What do I do to see my web-site created in the full view inside the preview view?

Answer (score 0):

When a new website is created in the Azure Portal, a default "home" page is created automatically in the site's root directory called `hostingstart.html`. The page's text is something along the lines of:

> This web site has been successfully created. There's nothing here yet.

It sounds like this is what you are seeing. There are (at least) 2 things you can do to get your site to display.

**Instruct Azure to ignore the file**

From the Azure Portal:

1. Go to the websites section and click on your website.
2. Go to the Configure tab.
3. Scroll down to the Default Documents section.
4. Remove the `hostingstart.html` entry.

**Delete the file**

From Visual Studio:

1. Open the Server Explorer.
2. Expand Azure > Websites > {YourWebsite} > Files.
3. Delete `hostingstart.html`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and will let you know. One thing I have noticed is that if I do it other way around and create the web-site from the Preview portal - I can see it display in both Preview and Full view portals